# call ajax in cakephp view form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am creating a view in which three dropdown will work 
   On select of role , request to server than name in another dropdown than request to server
   ,select  data and a new table is generated in view for user log.

I have written code but it is not working .

```
 user_activities.ctp

      <script type="text/javascript">var myBaseUrl = '<?php echo $this->base; ?>'
    var serverName='<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>';

    function getname(name) { 
        var strURL=myBaseUrl+('/manageUsers/userActivities/')+name;
            function getXMLHTTP() {
           var x = false;
           try {
              x = new XMLHttpRequest();
           }catch(e) {
             try {
                x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }catch(ex) {
                try {
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e1) {
                    x = false;
                }
             }
          }
          return x;
        }
      var req = getXMLHTTP();
      if (req) {
       req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
             // only if "OK"
                 if (req.status == 200) {      

            document.getElementById('manageUsersName').innerHTML=req.responseText;

             } else {
   alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                     }
        }    

       }   

       req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
       }  
     }


     </script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

$('#manageUsersRole').change(function(){ 
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    //var id=fieldName = $(this).attr('id');

    getname(selectedValue);

    $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
          url  : myBaseUrl+('/manageUsers/userActivities/')+selectedValue, //pass query    
  string to server
         success : function(opt)
         {
     document.getElementById('manageUsersName').innerHTML = opt;  
          }
        })
        });
        });

   </script>


    <?php echo $this->Form->create('manageUsers');

        $role = array('admin' => 'Admin', 'driver' => 'Driver');
          echo $this->Form->input('role',array('type' => 'select', 'options' => 
          $role,'label' => 'Select User Type','default' => 'driver'));
      echo $this->Form->input('name',array('type' => 'select','options'=>$userList,  
      'label' => 'Select User name'));
        ?>


  I don't know if url is generating true or not How can I check????
 and what data is coming from function



  public function userActivities($role=NULL)
{
    $this->loadModel('ActivityLog');

    $userLists = $this->ActivityLog->find('list', array(
     'fields' => array('ActivityLog.user_name'),
     'conditions' => array('ActivityLog.role =' => $role)

 ));

 $userList=array();
 foreach($userLists as $key=>$value )
 {
    $userList[$value]=$value;
 }


    $this->set('userList',$userList);

}
```

Request is going on server .  i have checked with firebug. On change is working 
    But no response is coming in 2nd dropdown. Only two values of 
     First dropdown are repeated in 2nd dropdown. Can you suggest some change.

Comment: what errors are you getting in network tab and in console?

Comment: Do you think my code is working .    I am getting  error                     ReferenceError: getXMLHTTP is not defined
 

var req = getXMLHTTP();

Comment: i have added this function now on top                                         function getXMLHTTP() {
            var x = false;
            try {
               x = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }catch(e) {
              try {
                 x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }catch(ex) {
                 try {
                     req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                 }
                 catch(e1) {
                     x = false;
                 }
              }
           }
           return x;
         }

Answer (score 0):

**my updated code is**

var myBaseUrl = 'base; ?>'
        var serverName='';

```
    function getXMLHTTP() {
           var x = false;
           try {
              x = new XMLHttpRequest();
           }catch(e) {
             try {
                x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }catch(ex) {
                try {
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e1) {
                    x = false;
                }
             }
          }
          return x;
        }

    function getname(name) { 
        var strURL=myBaseUrl+('/manageUsers/userActivities/')+name;
      var req = getXMLHTTP();
      if (req) {
       req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
             // only if "OK"
                 if (req.status == 200) {      
                  document.getElementById('manageUsersName').innerHTML=req.responseText;

                         } else {
                      alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                     }
        }    

       }   

       req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
       }  
     }
```

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('#manageUsersRole').change(function(){ 
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    //var id=fieldName = $(this).attr('id');

    getname(selectedValue);


        });
        });

   </script>


   <?php echo $this->Form->create('manageUsers');

       $role = array('admin' => 'Admin', 'driver' => 'Driver');
             echo $this->Form->input('role',array('type' => 'select', 'options' => 
       $role,'label' => 'Select User Type','default' => 'driver'));
       echo $this->Form->input('name',array('type' => 'select','options'=>$userList, 
   'label' => 'Select User name'));

   echo $this->Form->end('Submit');


 ?>

and controller code is 



     public function userActivities($role=NULL)
{
    $this->loadModel('ActivityLog');
    // $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $userLists = $this->ActivityLog->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('ActivityLog.user_name'),
    'conditions' => array('ActivityLog.role =' => $role)

));

$userList=array();
 foreach($userLists as $key=>$value )
 {
    $userList[$value]=$value;
 }


    $this->set('userList',$userList);

}



 Now only problem I am facing is I get two drop down .
   on selecting value on first dropdown, value changes in 2nd dropdown but in 2nd 

dropdown
 I  am getting values of 1st dropdown + values of server response
```

ex:
    on selecting admin from (Admin,Driver )
   i am getting in 2nd DropDown    (Admin,Driver,AdminName).

what is the problem in my code  .

I am getting html code in response
    Select User Type

```
    <option value="admin">Admin</option>

     <option value="driver" selected="selected">Driver</option>

     </select></div>
    <div class="input select"><label for="manageUsersName">Select User name</label>
     <select name="data[manageUsers][name]" id="manageUsersName">
     <option value="dipanshu">dipanshu</option>
  <option value="vivek">vivek</option>
 <option value="varun">varun</option>

    </select></div>
   <div class="submit"><input  type="submit" value="Submit"/></div></form>
```

Comment: Unless this is working now delete this answer and update your original question.